# Quant Software Toolkit

Tags: python, qstk

I am having some problems understanding the QSTK module. For example:

```
timestamps = du.getNYSEdays(dt_start, dt_end, dt_timeofday)
```

This gets me the timestamps for New York's stock exchange. But what if I wanted Hong Kong stock exchange or Tokyo stock exchange? How do I get that?

Comment: There are no other `getXXXXdays` functions in [QSTK's `qsdateutil`](https://github.com/QuantSoftware/QuantSoftwareToolkit/blob/master/QSTK/qstkutil/qsdateutil.py), so I guess they only fully support NYSE trading days.

Comment: The fastest way I used to get **`QSTK`** final answers is to ask Tucker or Sourabh. Do not hesitate to ask, Tucker is indeed a gentleman whom is a pleasure to work with.